# Alinear el texto/mensaje de un JOptionPane

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo varios **JOptionPane** que muestran mensajes, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, "          Login Successful");
```

Cuando escribo el mensaje como en el ejemplo, tengo que poner un espacio antes de **Login Successful** para que se vea alineado en la mitad del dialogo si no lo hago el mensaje se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no me gusta esteticamente.

Hay alguna forma de alinear el texto/mensaje sin tener que hacerlo manualmente con espacios en blanco?

**EDIT:**

Probe esto:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, new JLabel("Login Successful", JLabel.CENTER));
```

Y no funciona, el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOptionPane` tiene un `JLabel` dentro, por lo que nosotros podemos crear uno nuevo, instanciandolo de nuevo, y dándole los atributos que queramos:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, new JLabel("Login Successful", JLabel.CENTER));
```

Comment: Ya probe eso, pero el texto sigue apareciendo desalineado.

Comment: @BryanRomero Algo estas haciendo mal, a mi me centra perfectamente el label al JOptionPane. No se si tenga que ver, pero en vez de loginFrame, pasale null haber que pasa.

Comment: Probe con null sin resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Te podría proponer una solución rápida amigo, pero implica eliminar el ícono que tiene por defecto un `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(`*parámetros*`)` que es el que te sale aquí: [image: ícono]

para esto tienes que eliminar el ícono insertando estos parámetros en el método:
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginFrame, new JLabel("Login Successful", JLabel.CENTER), "Messaggio", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);`

Te quedaría algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchos años tarde, pero ahí está XD